# JavaScript OnExecute Functionality in IE10 browser

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, dom-events

How to invoke `OnExecute()` function in IE10 browser. When I try to run the below command (in console via <kbd>F12</kbd> Dev tools) it showing like this in IE10

```
>> OnExecute();
"'OnExecute' is undefined"
```

When I execute the same in IE8 it was like below,

```
>>OnExecute();
"Object expected"
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Why do you need OnExecute? Which moment in a page's lifecycle are you trying to listen for that isn't covered by modern DOM events?

Comment: i was trying to invoke OnExecute(); when the button is clicked. The button is working properly in ie8 but not in ie10.

Comment: ie10 or IE itself is a bug ;)

Comment: Don't be surprised if different IE version's (especially old ones) have different things defined. Microsoft does this with all their software - they change interfaces and apis with every version. I'd suggest looking up the MSDN for that, in case it's been deprecated or something. Although considering the reputation MSDN has, good luck :P